# Does the || operator in Postgres result in a blank result if one of the columns is blank?

Tags: postgresql, operator

I am running a query in Postgres using the `||` operator to concatenate some columns and it seems where one of the columns is blank the whole result is blank. Is that normal `||` behaviour?

With "blank" I mean `NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what "blank" means, `NULL` or the empty string.

- If it means `NULL`, then yes, that's normal. `SELECT 'ab' || NULL ;` will return null.
- If it means an empty string, then no. `SELECT 'ab' || '' ;` will return `'ab'`.

To avoid the issue, you can convert the nulls to empty string with `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(str1, '') || COALESCE(str2, '') || ... || COALESCE(strN, '')
```

or use `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()` functions - which ignore nulls:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(str1, str2, ..., strN)

SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS('', str1, str2, ..., strN)
```